# Texture Lookup in Vertex Shader

Tags: directx, hlsl

I'm trying to create a vertex shader that loads a texture and uses it to distort a sphere.  However even though the texture is seamless when its actually put on the sphere, the distortion has gaps between the triangles.  As seen in the image below.

[image]

I think somthing is going wrong when sampling the texture, but I'm not sure.  Here is the code I'm using for the vertex shader:

```
cbuffer MatrixBuffer
{
matrix worldMatrix;
matrix viewMatrix;
matrix projectionMatrix;
};

cbuffer ExplosionBuffer
{
float3 distortion;
float time;
};

Texture2D shaderTexture;
SamplerState SampleType;


//structs

struct VertexInputType
{
float4 position : POSITION;
float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
float3 normal : NORMAL;
};

struct PixelInputType
{
float4 position : SV_POSITION;
float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
float3 normal : NORMAL;
float4 deltaP : DELTAPOS;
};

//Vertex shader

PixelInputType ExplosionVertexShader(VertexInputType input)
{
PixelInputType output;


//sample the noise texture
uint3 sampleCoord = uint3(512*input.tex.x, 512*input.tex.y, 0);
float4 distex = shaderTexture.Load(sampleCoord);


//calculate the displacement based on noise tex and distortion buffer
float displacement;
displacement = distortion.x * distex.r + distortion.y * distex.g + distortion.z * distex.b;
displacement = displacement * 2;
displacement = distex.r + distex.g + distex.b;
input.position = input.position * (1 + displacement);

//set w to one for proper matrix calculations.
input.position.w = 1.0f;

// Calculate the position of the vertex against the world, view, and projection matrices.
output.position = mul(input.position, worldMatrix);
output.position = mul(output.position, viewMatrix);
output.position = mul(output.position, projectionMatrix);

// Store the input color for the pixel shader to use.
output.tex = input.tex;

output.normal = input.normal;

output.deltaP.x = displacement;

return output;
}
```

Comment: Do you use an index buffer for the sphere? That should avoid these holes because you have no duplicated vertices that end up at slightly different positions due to floating point errors.

Comment: These splits are only occuring on the seams where the model was unwrapped.  Since each of those vertices will have different uv coordinates I don't think they can be stored as the same vertex even though they have the same position.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, that you're sampling texels which are out of range.

The lines

```
//sample the noise texture
uint3 sampleCoord = uint3(512*input.tex.x, 512*input.tex.y, 0);
float4 distex = shaderTexture.Load(sampleCoord);
```

are sampling coordinates in [0,512] range, which goes out of bounds (assuming that you're using a 512² texture). The Load method expects input coordinates in [0,texturedimension-1].

Therefore the crack in your model can be explained with the note from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509694.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> **Note**  When one or more of the coordinates in Location exceed the u, v, or w mipmap level dimensions of the texture, Load returns zero in all components. Direct3D guarantees to return zero for any resource that is accessed out of bounds.

So the effected vertices are displaced with zero.